# regex delete html comments in wordpress

Tags: php, html-parsing

How do I delete all comments in wordpress, after the tag `</html>`?

example

```
</body></html> <!-- bla bla --><!-- more bla bla --><!--and more bla bla -->
```

replace in

```
</body></html>
```

I would one function to be included in my function.php theme.

thank you

Comment: Truncate the document length to `strpos($html_content,'</html>') + 7`?

Comment: @Brad Christie `<!-- </html> -->` inside the body tag or a script or whatever, and you are pretty screwed. :)

Comment: @user673315: If you had `<html><head>...</head><body>...<!--</html>-->...</body></html><!--more comments-->` it would only find the first `</html>` and improperly truncate.

Answer (score -1):

i found this:

If you put this in your functions.php, it will delete all the HTML comments that are in your code.

```
function callback($buffer) {
    $buffer = preg_replace('/<!--(.|s)*?-->/', '', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
function buffer_start() {
    ob_start("callback");
}
function buffer_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
}
add_action('get_header', 'buffer_start');
add_action('wp_footer', 'buffer_end');
```

Comment: Explained it a little better. :)